# Using proxy model as a signal sender

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have a proxy model.

```
class ProxyModel(ParentModel):
    objects = ProxyModelManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

I'm trying to define my proxy model as a sender.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=core_models.ProxyModel)
def test_receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("test receiver")
```

But the function is not called after the model is saved.

Is it possible to define proxy model as sender?  If so how can I do ?

Thanks.

Edit: I noticed that, If I save the object like so,

```
>>> from core.models Import ProxyModel
>>> p = ProxyModel.objects.get(name="Object Name")
>>> p.save()
>>> test receiver
```

The function is being called and prints "test receiver".
But, If I save same object via admin panel through parent model, It doesn't.

Comment: It should work. Did you save the instance through `ProxyModel` or through `ParentModel`?

Comment: @bdbd I edited my question with extra information about saving object.

Comment: Right. If you are using the parent model, this receiver will not be called. How about using the proxy for the admin? Or writing a similar signal for the parent model?